# Firefox Extension Panel doesnt open when more than one window is opened

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, panel, firefox-addon-sdk

I attached a panel for a button in Firefox, it works normally when only one browser window is open, but doesnt work as soon as more windows are being opened. Then it simply doesnt pop up anymore. This is my code in main.js:

```
var toolbarbutton = ToggleButton({

    id: "my_button",
    label: "button",
    icon: {
      "16": self.data.url("icon16.png")
    },
    tooltiptext: "text",
    onChange: handleChange
});

var panel_button = panel.Panel({

    contentURL: self.data.url("button.html"),
    height: 250, 
    onHide: handleHide,
    contentScriptFile:  [self.data.url("jquery-2.1.1.min.js"),
                         self.data.url("myscript.js")]

});

function handleChange(state) {
  if (state.checked) {
    panel_button.show({
      position: toolbarbutton
    });
  }
}

function handleHide() {
  toolbarbutton.state('window', {checked: false});
}
```

The handlechange function doesnt seem to do anything when multiple windows are open, but works fine when its just one. Anyone any Ideas why this is and how to fix it? Help is appreciated.

Edit:
Even if it works with one window, it stops working entirely as soon I open another one and doesnt work even if I close all windows except one.

Comment: What happens if you move `position: toolbarbutton` to the panel constructor?

Comment: Nothing, its the exact same problem, still only shows when just one browser window is open.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing in my project,  It throws an error about swapFrameLoaders method not been implemented.  Have you found a solution by any chance?